# Find and remove matching substrings from two data frames

Tags: r, string

I have two data frames: *df1* and *df2*

```
df1<- structure(list(sample_1 = structure(c(7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
3L), .Label = c("P41182;Q9HCP0", "Q09472", "Q9Y6H1;Q5T1J5", "Q9Y6I3", 
"Q9Y6Q9", "Q9Y6U3", "Q9Y6W5"), class = "factor"), sample_2 = structure(c(7L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("O15143", "P31908", "P3R117", 
"P41356;P54612;A41PH2", "P54112", "P61809;Q92831", "Q16835"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("sample_1", 
"sample_2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))


df2<- structure(list(subunits..UniProt.IDs. = structure(c(4L, 6L, 5L, 
12L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 11L, 13L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 7L), .Label = c("O55102,Q9CWG9,Q5U5M8,Q8VED2,Q91WZ8,Q8R015,Q9R0C0,Q9Z266", 
"P30561,O08915,P07901,P11499", "P30561,P53762", "P41182,P56524", 
"P41182,Q8WUI4", "P41182,Q9UQL6", "P61160,P61158,O15143,O15144,O15145,P59998,O15511", 
"P78537,Q6QNY1,Q6QNY0,Q9NUP1,Q96EV8,Q8TDH9,Q9UL45,O95295", "Q15021,Q9BPX3,Q15003,O95347,Q9NTJ3", 
"Q8WMR7,(P67776,P11493),(P54612,P54613)", "Q91VB4,P59438,Q8BLY7", 
"Q92793,Q09472,Q9Y6Q9,Q92831", "Q92828,Q13227,O15379,O75376,O60907,Q9BZK7", 
"Q92902,Q9NQG7", "Q92903,Q96NY9", "Q969F9,Q9UPZ3,Q86YV9"), class = "factor")), .Names = "subunits..UniProt.IDs.", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

I want to look at each semicolon-separated string in df1 and if it contains a match to one of the comma-separated strings in df2, then remove it.  So, my output will look like below:

```
       sample_1                  sample_2
1        Q9Y6W5                   Q16835
2        Q9Y6U3                   P61809
3                          P41356;A41PH2
4        Q9HCP0                   P3R117
5                                 P31908
6        Q9Y6I3                   P54112
7 Q9Y6H1;Q5T1J5
```

The sample_1 has strings in row 3, 4 and 5 that match one of the strings in df2, and those matching strings are removed.
The sample_2 has strings in row 2, 3 and 7 that match strings in df2, and those matching strings are removed.

Comment: If you make your data tidy with one column for each variable and one observation for each row, doing so is easy. As is, not so much.

Comment: @alistaire I don't know how to do it, if you know, please go ahead and give me a solution, I will surely accept , the method is not important for me but the answer is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could gather all the possible strings to remove:

```
toRmv <- unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df2[,1]), ",", fixed = TRUE)))
toRmv <- gsub("\\W", "", toRmv, perl = TRUE)
```

Then remove them.  I like the `stringi` package here for its ability to replace multiple strings with an empty string using the handy `vectorize_all` argument set to FALSE.

```
library(stringi) 
df1[] <- lapply(df1, stri_replace_all_fixed,
    pattern = toRmv, replacement = "", vectorize_all = FALSE)
df1
#       sample_1       sample_2
#1        Q9Y6W5         Q16835
#2        Q9Y6U3        P61809;
#3               P41356;;A41PH2
#4       ;Q9HCP0         P3R117
#5                       P31908
#6        Q9Y6I3         P54112
#7 Q9Y6H1;Q5T1J5
```

Now, it's just a matter of getting rid of leading semicolons (`^;`), trailing semicolons (`;$`), and multiple semicolons (`(?<=;);`):

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, gsub, pattern = "^;|;$|(?<=;);", replacement = "", perl = TRUE)
df1
#       sample_1      sample_2
#1        Q9Y6W5        Q16835
#2        Q9Y6U3        P61809
#3               P41356;A41PH2
#4        Q9HCP0        P3R117
#5                      P31908
#6        Q9Y6I3        P54112
#7 Q9Y6H1;Q5T1J5
```

As requested in the comment, here it is in function form.  I didn't test this part.  Feel free to test and adjust as you see fit:

```
stringRemove <- function(removeFrom, toRemove) {

    library(stringi)
    toRemove <- unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(toRemove), ",", fixed = TRUE)))
    toRemove <- gsub("\\W", "", toRemove, perl = TRUE)

    removeFrom[] <- lapply(removeFrom, stri_replace_all_fixed,
            pattern = toRemove, replacement = "", vectorize_all = FALSE)
    removeFrom[] <- lapply(removeFrom, gsub,
         pattern = "^;|;$|(?<=;);", replacement = "", perl = TRUE)
    removeFrom
}

# use it
stringRemove(removeFrom = df1, toRemove = df2[,1])
```

Comment: if you count the number of strings per each column of the output df1 and the df1, you will see they are the same , if you look at the dimension of it before and after, they are the same. that makes me sure that it does not work probably it is because of df2 input ? maybe it has like " and therefore influence on the results ?

Comment: @nik I don't expect the dimensions to change.  Just like in you example where the input df1 had 7 rows and 2 columns, and the output has 7 rows and 2 columns. I replaced matching substrings with empty strings: "".  No rows or columns were removed, and so the dimensions won't change.  So, it is working how I expect it to work, but if it's not what you want you may need to edit your question to clarify.

Comment: your solution is fast and it seems to work, would it be possible to revise it that I can make it as a function ? I already liked your answer once it is clean, I will definitely accept it. Thanks again

Comment: @nik I added a quick function version at the end.  You can change and refine it as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should almost definitely rearrange your data so it's tidy, i.e. has a column for each variable and a row for each observation, but not knowing what it is or how it's related, I can't do that for you. Thus, the only way left is to hack through what are effectively list columns:

```
library(dplyr)

        # For each column,
df1 %>% mutate_each(funs(
    # convert to character,
    as.character(.) %>% 
        # split each string into a list of strings to evaluate,
        strsplit(';') %>% 
        # loop over the items in each list,
        lapply(function(x){
            # replacing any in a similarly split and unlisted df2 with NA,
            ifelse(x %in% unlist(strsplit(as.character(df2[,1]), '[(),]+')), 
                NA_character_, x)
        }) %>% 
        # then loop over them again,
        sapply(function(x){
            # removing NAs where there are non-NA strings.
            ifelse(all(is.na(x)), list(NA_character_), list(x[!is.na(x)]))
        })))

#         sample_1       sample_2
# 1         Q9Y6W5         Q16835
# 2         Q9Y6U3         P61809
# 3             NA P41356, A41PH2
# 4         Q9HCP0         P3R117
# 5             NA         P31908
# 6         Q9Y6I3         P54112
# 7 Q9Y6H1, Q5T1J5             NA
```

If you want to collapse the actual list columns you end with back into strings, you can do so with `paste`, but really, list columns are more useful.

---

**Edit**

If your data is big enough that it's worth the annoyance to make it faster, take the munging of `df2` out of the chain and store it separately so you don't calculate it for every iteration. Here's a version that does so, built in [`purrr`](https://github.com/hadley/purrr), which works with lists instead of data.frames and can be faster than `mutate_each` for non-trivial functions. Edit as you like.

```
library(purrr)

df2_unlisted <- df2 %>% map(as.character) %>%    # convert; unnecessary if stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                    map(strsplit, '[(),]') %>%    # split
                    unlist()    # unlist to vector

df1 %>% map(as.character) %>%    # convert; unnecessary if stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    map(strsplit, ';') %>%    # split
    at_depth(2, ~.x[!.x %in% df2_unlisted]) %>%    # subset out unwanted
    at_depth(2, ~if(is_empty(.x)) NA_character_ else .x) %>%    # insert NA for chr(0)
    as_data_frame() %>% data.frame()    # for printing
```

Results are identical.

Comment: I liked two of your answers just to make it up to you that you have spent time on this question. however, the time for the first algorithm is faster. thanks again for the time you put on my question , thanks